# Instagram App is removing return url from URL

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Instagram API to get the feeds. I am passing the current page URL like http://example.com in button. Which first redirects me to the Instagram authorization page and then returns the access token and **current_page_url** (passed in the query string) on redirect URI registered in Instagram APP.

But the only issue I have is if the user is not logged into https://www.instagram.com/ it first shows the login form and then provide access token which is good but it removes **current_page_url** from the query string and returns only access token to the redirect URI registered in Instagram APP.

Following is the authorization button URL.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id{client_id}&scope=basic+public_content&redirect_uri={valid_redirect_uri}?return_uri={current_page_url}&response_type=token
```

Let me know anything needed.

Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to pass `?return_uri=…` as part of your redirect_uri …? Then you need to properly URL-encode it of course.

Comment: No return_uri is not the part of redirect_uri. I didn't try encoding the URL let me try that though.

Comment: Nope. it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is this an official parameter of the Instagram auth endpoint then? Guess you could put that value into your own session instead, before you send the user to the login dialog, if you need it afterwards to redirect them back to the page they were on.

Comment: No, it's not an official parameter of auth endpoint. Actually, I am making it a plugin and so many users can use it so how and where can I store the current URL in session and get that on my website URL which is valid redirect url?

Comment: _“No, it's not an official parameter of auth endpoint.”_ - well then it would have to be part of your redirect_uri, otherwise I can not see that making any sense to begin with; what should passing a random parameter to an endpoint that doesn’t even care about it achieve? If you want to get this back as a query string parameter when the user is redirected back to your application, then it must be part of your redirect URI. And you would have to URL-encode the whole thing as value of the redirect_uri parameter, not just the “second part” on its own.

Comment: I guess it's the part of redirect_uri by using "?" if I use "&" after redirect_uri parameter  it throws an error "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"

Comment: I did trying encoding all in once but still I get error "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"

Comment: Ah yeah, I thought this might be similarly restricted as is the case with Facebook login. They don’t allow for “dynamic” redirect URIs, but only to use one from a list of specified values. Facebook’s mechanism has one exception, the `state` parameter - not sure if it’s the same for Instagram login. But I would really rather do this via the session in the first place.

Comment: Yeah you are right it's same like Facebook API mechanism we have to register the  redirect URL into APP reviwed by their team.

Can you please guide me how can I do it by session method?

Comment: You store the current URL into the session, before you send the user to the login dialog, so that you can read the value back from there after they are redirected back to your redirect URI.

Comment: Means first I redirect the user to the my site (registred_url) and save the URL in session and then send it to the Authorization page and after returning with access token I will get the URL saved in session and return back.
Right?

Comment: Yes, if you want this to work in a situation where the user might have multiple pages of your site open in multiple tabs, and then clicks the login button in a random one of them, then you will have to store the URL of that page into the session at the moment when the click that link. So you could do something like `<a href="redirect_me_to_login.php?current_page={current page URL}">Login</a>`, and then in that script, you put the value of the parameter into the session, and redirect to the login dialog URL afterwards.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much for the help really appreciated. I am gonna do it right now.

Comment: yeah, it's working now but I used the cookie instead of the session because multiple users are visiting the session stored page at the same time so I don't want to get replaced the URL with another user. The cookie will store the URL for each user separately. BTW Thanks again.

Comment: Huh? Sessions usually _are_ user-specific, resp. client-specific to be more precises (unless you explicitly implemented something else.)

Comment: I am confused in session and cookie I searched about it but they said session would store data on server and cookie will save as a file in the computer so I guess.

Comment: Yes, session data is stored on the server - but individually for each client, via the random session id that the client sends back with every request.

Comment: ahhh, got it Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, Instagram App removes url parameters without name like `...?someid&etc=...`, forcing you to use a name, like`...?client_id=someid&etc=...`.